# I get this error "ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to update a table eg like this,

```
string query = "UPDATE x SET y = 0 where z = '300250' ";
    try
    {
        using(con)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

but I cannot get the con to be initialized.

I have a code like this that runs without any problems.

```
 string email="";
    try {
        string query = "select Email from UserTbl where NameId = '" + userName+"'";
        using (con)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    email = dr.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I have spent all day on this. 
What am I missing?

Comment: How do you create `con`? post connection string and related code to create `SqlConnection`

Comment: I guess you are using `SqlConnection` in several `using(con)` block, after first `using` block `con` get disposed and you no longer can use it inside another `using` block. if you post full code it will help more.

Comment: @Mohsen Esmailpour. Nice guess. Yes, that was it. What is the way around that? Wrapping a whole class in one using(con){ }?

Comment: @TheNewone, instead of `using (con)`, instantiate a new connection each `using` so each block has its own instance. For example, `using (var con = MyConnectionFactory.GetConnection())`